# how to access webform submission data from a custom content type

Tags: webforms

I 'd be grateful if someone could help with this..

I have a webform, let's call it **input form**, which, when submitted, triggers an external application to run on my server.  That application uses some of the submission data (reading from webform_submission_data table) and after some time produces an output in the form of XML.

Now, through the use of [feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds), I read that XML data and produce a node, of a certain content type, let's call it **results** CT ..

I have a twig template for the *results* content type, and output is nicely presented to the user.

So far, so good.

Now my problem is this.  I need to show both input and output in the same *results* page.

I tried to use [Webform Content Creator](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_content_creator) module and indeed I have nodes with submission data - let's call this **input data** CT.

However, at the time of *input form submission*, I don't have the *results* yet.  And I want to link the two together, obviously upon the creation of the *results* node.

I tried to reference each content type, using [Corresponding Entity References](https://www.drupal.org/project/cer) so that when a **results** node is created (automatically through feeds) it would link to the corresponding **input data** CT.  I thought that if I can achieve that connection, then I would be able to access the 'input' data through the results page template.

However, I can't make this connection to work - the 'entity reference' field that I use on the results CT, wants an 'entity ID' - and I can't find that.  Remember that nodes are created automatically, I don't have a user creating nodes via a select form or autocomplete text field.

I am trying to figure out how to do this through the *sid* (submission id) which seems to be a unique key for every submission, and I have this on both my content types .. So ideally I would like to use the *sid* that I have on my *results* template, and use that to get the submission data I need.

(obviously) I am not very familiar with the drupal API - I am however comfortable with twig .. I don't know if (and how) I could pass that information through a pre-process function to be available in the *results* template..  Is there a simpler way to do it?

Could I link two content types based on a custom field (say a unique number, like *sid* ??).

**Ideally, in a few words, what I want is this:**

*I have a CT (**results**) with various fields, one of which is **sid**.  That sid corresponds to a (unique) submission id.  How can I access data relevant to that submission id **from within the results twig template**?  So I can then present both input (submission data) and output (results) in the same page.*

PS - Perhaps one solution would be to refactor the whole logic, and use one CT for both input/output.  Insert some data upon form submission, and then, when results are ready, edit (i.e. fill-in) the rest of the 'output' fields via feeds.  Then all data are in one CT.  However I would rather avoid this as it's quite a big change ..  Shamefully enough, I might just re-enter input data through the XML again - it wouldn't be a problem - but it's a really crap solution  ..

I 'd be really grateful if someone could help .. I hope I explained the whole situation adequately enough ..

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish that would be to use the https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_entity_handler module. It is not very widely used module yet but I've used it, it was simple to use and worked well. What that module does it allows you to create arbitrary entity from a webform submission (like the **results** node). So you could store the input, submission id and whatever else you need to this entity at this time.

Then feeds can update this same entity with the results if you know unique identifier like the submission id.